# Meter in Tennyson's *Maud*

Tags: poetry, meter

How should Tennyson's [*Maud*](http://www.bartleby.com/42/6491.html) be read? I.e. what is its meter? Here are the first four lines:

> I HATE the dreadful hollow behind the little wood, 
>   Its lips in the field above are dabbled with blood-red heath,
>   The red-ribb’d ledges drip with a silent horror of blood, 
>   And Echo there, whatever is ask’d her, answers “Death.”

Comment: If only we could [ask Tennyson](http://books.google.com/books?id=drlWONjjVe0C&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=maud+read+aloud+tennyson&source=bl&ots=Vpi-1kT4jU&sig=KxTSQ4L-3T-tWM_K4OBaEu5J4hI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OKpoT9yjE-Xb0QGbsbzuCA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=maud%20read%20aloud%20tennyson&f=false).

Comment: Looks like mainly iambic hexameter to me. But there is variance.

Comment: @Robusto But *none* of the lines have 12 syllables. Does that matter? Should some syllables be "merged"?

Comment: @Quinn: It doesn't have to have 12 syllables. It's all about the stresses of the metrical feet. There are six in each line. Why do you think it's called *hexameter* and not *duodecameter*? Shakespeare's sonnets are all in iambic pentameter, yet you find lines like "Thou art more beautiful and more temperate." Metric poetry isn't about strict adherence to numerical exactness. That would be boring.

Comment: See my answer, Tennyson wrote the poem deliberately breaking the "rules" of meter.

Comment: @Robusto: Whether it would be "boring" is subjective and debatable. Strict adherence is hard in English, so variation is tolerated and welcomed. :P It's not universal to all languages.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Variation is not merely tolerated, it is a hallmark of good writing. Bad, lock-step metrical poetry gets sing-songy over time, and masters of the art know this. Look at the works of any of the great poets and you will find variations on meter — not because the poets found the task of creating perfect meter too difficult, but because it was not what they wanted to express. Look at Robert Pinsky's *The Sounds of Poetry* for elaboration on these ideas.

Comment: @Robusto: Again, you mean "great poets *in English*" (and a handful of other related languages) — a look at the table of contents/index of Pinsky's book doesn't suggest it's any less parochial in its subject matter. Yes, verses that are all strictly in a particular metre can all be recited in that metre — this is almost a tautology, but whether such repetition/consistency is good, or "sing-songy" and bad, is subjective and culture- and language-specific. No big deal here, this is English.SE after all; I just wanted to point out that the feeling was not universal.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Forgive me for assuming that this was the *English* Language & Usage site. I don't know how I could have done that.

Comment: @Robusto: My original comment was to the effect that your remark is fine for English, but is not universal to all languages. And re-reading my comment, that's the meaning that still seems to come across (but of course it would to me, since I wrote it myself not too long ago :-)). Do you think I could have phrased it more clearly?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The point you seemed to be making was that metrical variation was "tolerated and welcomed" in English because it was hard. I disputed that. Still do. End of story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Maud* is well known for having been written in an [unstable and varying meter](http://books.google.com/books?id=DlMUSz-hiuEC&lpg=RA4-PA148&ots=AGmEeRc6_9&dq=Meter%20and%20linguistics%20in%20Tennyson%27s%20%22Maud.%22&pg=RA4-PA148#v=onepage&q=Meter%20and%20linguistics%20in%20Tennyson%27s%20%22Maud.%22&f=false); there have been [many](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/40002314?uid=3739840&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=47698781931877) [studies](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/35045275/morbid-meters-maud) [made](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maud_and_other_poems#Interpretation_of_Maud) of this.

> ...*Maud* is a metrical sampler in which the poet displayed his
>   virtuosity in an array of complex meters and stanza forms.

-from *[The Oxford Encyclopedia of British Literature](http://books.google.com/books?id=DlMUSz-hiuEC&lpg=RA4-PA148&ots=AGmEeRc6_9&dq=Meter%20and%20linguistics%20in%20Tennyson%27s%20%22Maud.%22&pg=RA4-PA148#v=onepage&q=Meter%20and%20linguistics%20in%20Tennyson%27s%20%22Maud.%22&f=false)*

**EDIT**: The University of Cambridge has [some audio readings](http://www.english.cam.ac.uk/multimedia/tennyson/maud.htm) that should be instructive.